# Is there any way to create a HOC that uses methods from the WrappedComponent?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I wanted to create an auto-refresh-HOC that looks more or less like this:

```
export function withAutoRefresh(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(p: Readonly<any>) {
      super(p);
    }

    interval: NodeJS.Timeout;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => theFunctionToRefreshWhichIsFromTheWrappedComponent(), 5000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  };
}
```

My problem is now, that the function which I want to refresh, is only available within the `WrappedComponent`. Is there any way to achieve this or something similar to what I have described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually very easy and I found a way.
I only need to add a state to this component with a `refreshFunction` attribute and pass a setter function as a prop to the `WrappedComponent`. A draft looks more or less like that:

```
constructor(p: Readonly<any>) {
    super(p);
    this.state = {
        refreshFunction: () => void 0
    }
}

...

setRefresh(newFunction) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        refreshFunction: newFunction
    })
}

render() {
  return (
    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} setRefresh={this.setRefresh} />
  );
}
```